# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ngRoute in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

[image]
This is My Angular Code on top it is showing that ***angular is not defined***. I have written this code to test routing concept in angular js

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: '/Directive/pages/main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/second', {
            templateUrl: 'Directive/pages/second.html',
            controller: 'secondController'
        })
        .when('/second:num', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
            controller: 'secondController'
        })
});
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $log.info='mainController';
    $scope.name = 'Main';

}]);

app.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $log.warn='From Second';  
    $scope.name = 'Second';

}]);
app.directive('searchResult', function () {
    return {
        template: 'ABC',

    }
});
```

For more information please look into my HTML file if any changes I need to do in place of CDN so please let me know as in the **browser it is showing Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        input,
        select,
        textarea {
            font-size: 1.05em;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- load angular via CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">AngularJS</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="pages/main.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Main</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/second.html"><i></i> Second</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div ng-view>From ngView</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to pass `ngRoute` in

Comment: on browser console it is displaying  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?.......

Comment: please look into image that <ng-view> is commented

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The code works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/egllfCuCOTgC1FRczgvL?p=preview).

Comment: can anyone tell me why in browser console <ng-view > is commented

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
>
> This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.
>
> A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.
>
> ### Using ngRoute
>
> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

Comment: Already gone through this but can you please look into my code and tell me why it is not working